# Regular Expression/JS – remove content from specific xml tags and keep only text

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I’d like to remove content from specific tags and keep only the text. I’m using Javascript but on React Native, so I can’t use Dom or JQuery.

For example, for this input, I’d like to remove all the sub-tags of "li":

```
<div>
     <div><span>hello</span></div>  
     <ul>
         <li><div><span>hello 2</span></div></li>
         <li><div><span>hello 3</span></div></li>
     </ul>       
</div>
```

I’d like to get this output:

```
<div>
     <div><span>hello</span></div>  
     <ul>
         <li>hello 2</li>
         <li>hello 3</li>
     </ul>       
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? (again, not using DOM or JQuery)

Thank you!

Comment: Regular expressions are a nightmare for processing markup languages. Have you looked at using React Native DOM/HTML parsers like [this one](https://github.com/g6ling/react-native-html-parser)?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks! you mean nightmare in the sense of performance or other reason? I will check out the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a native JavaScript way to filter out specific tags within `<li>` tags:

```js
var str =
'<div>\n' +
'     <div><span>hello</span></div>\n' +
'     <ul>\n' +
'         <li><div><span>hello 2</span></div></li>\n' +
'         <li><div><span>hello 3</span></div></li>\n' +
'     </ul>\n' +
'</div>';
var re1 = /(<li> *)(.*?)(<\/li>)/g;
var re2 = /<\/?(div|span)\b[^>]*> */g;
var result = str.replace(re1, function(m, p1, p2, p3) {
    return p1 + p2.replace(re2, '') + p3;
});
console.log('result:\n' + result);
```

Console output:

```
result:
<div>
     <div><span>hello</span></div>
     <ul>
         <li>hello 2</li>
         <li>hello 3</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Explanation:

- `re1` identifies `<li>` tags

  - it has the `g` flag to match multiple times
  - the replace function has three capture groups as parameters `p1`, `p2`, `p3`
- the replace function removes all `div` and `span` tags from `p2`, which is the content within the `<li>` tag

  - tweak the `re2` to add additional tags to filter
  - it also has the `g` flag to match multiple times

Comment: Thanks @peter – works great!
And thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting this answer.